# Convert async await in while loop to promises

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I can't figure out how to convert async await functionality in a while loop to a promise based implementation.

repl showing the async await version

https://repl.it/repls/IdealisticPepperyCoding

```js
var dependency = false;

function checkDependency() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      dependency = true;
      return resolve();
    }, 1000)
  });
}

async function isReady() {
    while(!dependency) {
      console.log('not loaded');
      await checkDependency();
    }
    console.log('loaded')
}

isReady();
```

Comment: What did you try that didn’t work

Comment: Removed async await and tried checkDependency().then()

Comment: Uh, async-await *is* promise-based, so I'm not sure what you're asking about? Does the code work or not, what's the problem?

Comment: Btw, your `checkDependency` function should resolve the returned promise with the boolean value, not mutate some global `dependency` variable.

Comment: I'm guessing this is far from "actual code", because there are about 100 better ways to write this :p

Comment: @ZackLucky, it seems that you have a stream for `false/true` values. You could consider using [RxJS stream extensions](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're wanting to use Promises *without* async functions instead of Promises *with* async functions, and the sample `checkDependency` may actually not set `dependency = true` in all cases, so you want to "loop."

Equivalent functionality could look something like this, where you "recursively" call the check function. It won't actually be recursive and lead to a stack overflow, though, since the call is done in an async callback:

```
var dependency = false;

function checkDependency() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      dependency = true;
      return resolve();
    }, 1000)
  });
}

function isReady() {
  if (!dependency) {
    return checkDependency().then(isReady);
  }

  return Promise.resolve(true);
}

isReady().then(() => {
  console.log('loaded')
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the while loop.

```html
checkDependency().then(() => { console.log('loaded');});
```

Comment: My fault the `dependency = true` in the promise isn't always true in which case it needs to check again when it is

Comment: @ZackLucky, it seems that you have a stream for `false/true` values. You could consider using [RxJS stream extensions](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/).

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to return `recolve()` just call it.
- Call the function `then` within the function `isReady`

```js
function checkDependency() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
  });
}

function isReady() {
  console.log('not loaded');
  checkDependency().then(() => {
    console.log('loaded')
  });
}

isReady();
```